# What is the command to bring up GUI shutdown box?

Tags: command-line, shutdown

Unity brings up a window with shutdown/reboot options when pressed my pc power button. But how to do that with a command?

Comment: The command you're looking for is `gnome-session-quit`

Comment: Yeah, it is answered in the question above. Thanks :)